# How do I use Google Play discount on CATS: Crash Arena Turbo Stars?

Tags: google-play-games, cats-crash-arena-turbo-stars

I seem to be having the same issue everybody else is having. I can't get the Google Play discount coupon I used my points on to work. I looked online, and everybody's either saying it does it on checkout, to go into payment methods and apply it, or to go to Google Play Points and buy it.
Which I already did, but I did all of those, and there is neither a discount price on the in-game item nor an option in the payment methods next to Google Pay credits to select the discount.

Any ideas why it won't work? And yes, I am trying to buy an item equal to or above the price of the discount coupon, so it should work.